# Brand New Macbook Pro 15" Battery

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I just bought a brand new 15" Macbook Pro (mid 2014) and it came with already 2 battery cycle counts, is that normal?

Comment: presumably, someone had to test it at the factory

Comment: Anything less than 3-4 cycles, I'm OK with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is great. It sounds like Apple tests their hardware well before sending it out.

Obviously without asking them you can't know for sure, but presumably those two battery counts are to ensure that the battery that you have in the laptop right now is a good battery that performs to spec.

Comment: Spot on!  Apple doesn't produce batteries, they buy them from a supplier which produces them according to Apple specs.  If a new battery has a couple extra cycles on it compared to other new ones, it's most probably because they have been pulled 'blindly' from the production line for additional batch/spot testing as per Apple mandatory QC requirements.   On top of that Apple's production line has similar tests: one overnight burn in test and regular blind batch pulls.  All these tests are done in the most extreme perfect conditions, making your battery better rather than worse than others.